# Integrating by parts in $H_0^1$ space

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

In a paper I am reading, we have two functions $u,v \in H^1_0$ where the relation

$$\int_\Omega \textbf{b} \cdot \nabla u v = -\int_\Omega \textbf{b} \cdot \nabla v u - \int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \textbf{b} u v$$

is given. Where $\textbf{b}$ is a non-zero constant vector. The paper states that this can be achieved through integration by parts, but I am struggling to see how using integration by parts can achieve this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the divergence theorem, if $\Phi \in C_c^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^N)$ then
$$\int_\Omega \nabla \cdot \Phi= 0$$
and the same holds by density (with respect to the Sobolev norm) for $\Phi \in H_0^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^N)$. By putting $\Phi=uv\mathbf{b}$ and differentiating we get
$$\int_\Omega (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{b}) uv+ \int_\Omega (\mathbf{b} \cdot \nabla u) v + \int_\Omega (\mathbf{b} \cdot \nabla v) u=0$$
This can be actually seen as a generalization of integration by parts, with null value at the boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can I just clarify that $\Phi \in C_c^1(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^N)$ means that $\Phi$ has compact support and will be $0$ on the boundary? And that you have split the integral using a product rule on $\nabla \cdot (uv \textbf{b})$?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: The rule is $\nabla \cdot u\mathbf{V}= u(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{V})+ \nabla u \cdot \mathbf{V}$ for $u$ scalar and $\mathbf{V}$ vector function

Comment: That's great, thanks.